# Passing List<Integer> with reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I have a Java method:

```
  public void setPri(List<Integer> pri) { this.pri = pri; }
```

What I want to do is call the method and pass a List.  What is the correct approach using reflection?

I was trying the following:

```
  method = object.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setPri", List.class);
  method.invoke(null,new Object[] { pri });
```

Comment: Did you start by reading the javadoc of the methods you are using?

Comment: If you tried something and it failed, explain how it failed.

Comment: Also, generics is a compile time concept. Reflection is a run time concept.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code won't primarily work, because you are not passing an instancs as first parameter:

```
method.invoke(null,new Object[] { pri });
```

You need to pass `object` as first parameter, not `null`.

This should work:

```
List<Integer> pri = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4);
Method method = object.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setPri", List.class);
method.invoke(object, new Object[] { pri });
```

Comment: Sorry, it was not clear, what `pri` was exactly, but you are right, of course. Corrected my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  Been going on 3 hours of sleep in the last 30 hours.  I need a vacation.